# Как создавать изолированные копии БД под разных пользователей?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, nestjs, sequelize.js

Помогите разобраться вот в таком вопросе. Предположим у нас есть CRM система и нам хочется что бы этой системой мог пользоваться любой зарегистрировавшийся пользователь. У этой CRM естественно есть база данных. Хочется сделать так что бы при регистрации пользователя создавалась копия базы данных под него, и данные разных пользователей не пересекались а лежали изолированно в своей копии БД. Подскажите как такое можно сделать на автомате и какие технологии могут потребоваться. Изначальный стек: сервер nest.js, ORM sequelize, БД postgresql.

Comment: Ищите по термину multi tenant. / [Вот](https://medium.com/@badenjki/build-a-multi-tenant-nodejs-app-with-sequelize-and-cilo-part-1-7f886c30b89c), например, что-то есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [Postgresql схемы](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/15/ddl-schemas).

При регистрации пользователя запускать скрипт, который будет создавать схему под пользователя и копировать туда начальные данные.

Например: в стандартной схеме `public` вы храните внутренние данные CMS: Зарегистрированные в ней пользователи, названия схем, и т.п. А во всех остальных схемах будет лежать база для каждого пользователя.

Остается лишь создать middleware (точный код на nestJS я привести не смогу, но думаю [Вот эта статья](https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql/) будет очень полезной), который будет для каждого пользователя менять текущую схему на ту, которая принадлежит пользователю. А дальше весь код будет по умолчанию выполняться для каждого пользователя в его личной базе данных.